# Where are ES5 files generated from Typescript by webpack in Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack-dev-server

According to [Angular2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html#!#from-ts), TypeScript is at final downgraded to ES5.
my question is when I run the app (npm run server, or npm start) how can have access to ES6-with-decorators or ES5 translated files of Angular2 app. 
the current app I have now is created by webpack-angular2-starter.

I need the ES6 or ES5 files for complexity analysis, cause I am using [Plato](https://github.com/es-analysis/plato) that I think is the best in this work.

Comment: Is your question "How do I remove TypeScript type decorations from ES6 code?"

Comment: No, my question is where are those ES6 files? browsers work with JS not TS

Comment: You should put your question into your title and your post.

Comment: @Rob sure, edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack-dev-server is serving all of our files from memory.
though in the `webpack.dev.js` the output is defined as `path: helpers.root('dist'),` where helper by default has the path to root of the project but you can not see any folder called `dist`.
the easiest way is to install webpack globally and just command `webpack` or in this case `npm run build:prod` then the `dist` folder is getting generated in the root of the project

Answer (score -1):

> I need the ES6 files...

They don't exist separately from the TypeScript files unless you create them. The TypeScript compiler can be told what kind of output to generate (ES3, ES5, ES6/ES2015, etc.) via the [`--target option`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), e.g., `--target ES2015` (or its synonym `--target ES6`).

So if you need ES6 files for complexity analysis, you can use the TypeScript compiler to read the TypeScript files and output ES6 files.

Comment: *(If you don't see an actual link above, hit refresh. Or if you see identical "synonyms." Oops.)*

Comment: in the tsconfig.json  there is  "compilerOptions": {"target": "es5" ...   but there is no dis folder or something to see them , or even in the chrome console I do not see .js files

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi: That means you're generating ES5, not ES6, files. Assuming you're run the compilation step, they're there somewhere. Look for the `outDir` and `outFile` (formerly, `out`) options.